# Setting the document root in godaddy virtual server

Tags: apache-2.2

HI,
I am not familiar with setting up servers. I want to set up the document root to point to another directory. This is not mod rewrite for URL's that I am trying to do.

Is it a httpd.conf file or a .htaccess that I need to create? and what is the code to do it??

Answer (score 0):

1. In apache\conf\httpd.conf file, find and change the DocumentRoot property, such as:

   `DocumentRoot "C:/apache/htdocs"`
2. Restart your apache server.

Comment: The document root says <Directory "/var/www/html"> In the godaddy control panel it says that the document root that I want to change to should be:/home/myusername/public_html. Do I change it to: /var/www/html/home/myusername/public_html

Comment: No, I think it should be /home/myusername/public_html/